# What does it mean when DataFrame invoke a drop() without parameter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I see a code from book "Spark The Definitive Guide",it invoke a drop on a dataframe with no parameter,when I use show(),I found nothing changed,but what is the meaning of it?

I execute it,nothing changed,dfNoNull.show() is the same as dfWithDate.show()

```
dfWithDate.createOrReplaceTempView("dfWithDate")
// in Scala
val dfNoNull = dfWithDate.drop()
dfNoNull.createOrReplaceTempView("dfNoNull")
```

does it mean, it create a new datarframe?
I know when a dataframe join itself when I using Hive sql,if I just

```
val df1=spark.sql("select id,date from date")
val df2=spark.sql("select id,date from date")
val joinedDf = spark.sql("select dateid1,dateid2 from sales")
.join(df1,df1["id"]===dateid1).join(df2,df2["id"]===dateid2)
```

Then an error occur:Cartesian join!
because the lazy evalution will consider df1 and df1 as the same one

so here,if I

```
val df2=df1.drop()
```

will I prevent that error?

If not,what does the drop method with no parameter mean?

Or it just mean remove the temp view name and create a new one?

but I try the code below,no exception throwed:

```
   val df=  Seq((1,"a")).toDF("id","name")
   df.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
   val df2=df.drop()
    df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
    spark.sql("select * from df1").show()
```

Or does the book mean below?

```
 val dfNoNull = dfWithDate.na.drop()
```

because it wrote somewhere below the code:

> Grouping sets depend on null values for aggregation levels. If you do
>   not filter-out null values, you will get incorrect results.This
>   applies to cubes, rollups, and grouping sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drop function with no parameter behave the same as drop with column name that doesn't exist in the Dataframe.
You can follow the code in the source of spark.

Even in the function documentation you can see a hint to this behavior.

```
  /**
   * Returns a new Dataset with a column dropped. This is a no-op if schema doesn't contain
   * column name.
   *
   * This method can only be used to drop top level columns. the colName string is treated
   * literally without further interpretation.
   *
   * @group untypedrel
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
```

So when calling the function with no parameter no-op occur and nothing changes in the returning DataFrame.